# Pass data from one view model to other using typescript

Tags: variables, typescript, global, argument-passing

I am new to typescript, What I want to do is post data from one view (using corresponding viewmodel for that view) and get some return data from the server(controller) which is a JSON object and pass this returned data to the next view model (and show it in the next view).
I would like to do that using Typescript. I am using some code (which I want use commonly to submit all views) like below in module with name common.

```
export var commonData;

function SubmitPage(url: string, dataToPost: JSON, nextPage: string) {
    $.post(url, dataToPost, function (returnedData, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == 'success') {
          commonData = returnedData;
          router.navigate(nextPage);
        }
        else {
            ShowErrorMessage(returnedData);
        }
    })
}
```

Here I can see the returnedData coming back from the server, and I am assigning to a variable commonData and want to access it in another view model, basically I want commonData to be globally accessible in all view models. 
  in my other view model I am using some thing like this

```
import common = require('common');
var data = ko.toJS(common.CommonData);
```

where common is the name of the module where commonData is defined. 
Right now I see commonData as undefined. 
I know I am missing something very basic and doing some thing wrong, but not able to figure out. 
Please help. 
Thanks 
Ira

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Yes I know something is very wrong, but what is the solution. I am not very proficient with Typescript.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.  Rolling back to the one that makes sense with the answer that someone has kindly spent some time giving you.

Answer (score 2):

When this line executes :

```
import common = require('common');
```

the following is going to be run:

```
var commonData;    
function SubmitPage(url: string, dataToPost: JSON, nextPage: string) {
    // whatever 
}
```

All you've effectively done is define a variable and a function. `commonData` is not going to be set (and therefore will be `undefined`) unless you call SubmitPage *and* the xhr completes.